# Is it possible to using Image.getSize with static image file?

Tags: image, react-native, static-files

I want to use Image.getSize (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html) to get the size of my image but the first argument require the image source to be in URI but I can't use URI with static file, I can only use Require.

Therefore, is it possible is to use Image.getSize on static file or do I have to find another way?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use *resolveAssetSource* (from [react-native/Libraries/Image/resolveAssetSource](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Image/resolveAssetSource.js)) to get the image's size.

```
import resolveAssetSource from 'resolveAssetSource';
```

and

```
let icon =  require('./assets/images/icon.png'); 
let source = resolveAssetSource(icon);
// source.width, source.height`
```

Comment: Hi! I edited your code sections and put them into code blocks. You can use the `{}` button in the editor to do this yourself. Can you add a reference to the package you are mentioning here? That would make this a great answer.

Comment: @Pekka웃, I might be wrong, but I used require : `const resolveAssetSource = require('resolveAssetSource');`

Comment: Succeed with `import resolveAssetSource from 'react-native/Libraries/Image/resolveAssetSource';`

Comment: I am trying to use resolveAssetSource in my code, but I am failing.

The following includes an example for what I am doing: https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image/issues/410#issuecomment-650614622

Can you explain what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 13):

You can use `Image.resolveAssetSource(source).width` and `Image.resolveAssetSource(source).height`.

Reference in React Native docs: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html#resolveassetsource

Answer (score 11):

Through [official document](https://reactnative.dev/docs/image#resolveassetsource)

```js
import { Image } from 'react-native'

const url = require('./x.png')
const image = Image.resolveAssetSource(url)
```

Then use `image.width` and `image.height`

Answer (score 1):

```
let path = "file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/xxx.jpg";
Image.getSize(path,(w,h)=>{
        console.log('w h=',w,h);
    },(err)=>{
        console.log('err....',err);
    })
```

Comment: Is it a good idea?I don't think so this should only work on andorid not ios.

Comment: The Image.getSize method can get only remote image dimensions not static/local image dimensions. ref [link](https://tutorialscapital.com/react-native-retrieve-remote-image-dimensions-android-ios-tutorial/)