# How to get remote image dimensions?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am building simple application, but one problem is I lost a lot of time, that's why I write here, I have images in my app that I get from another server, I need to know the original size of the image, I used to use React-native **getSize()** method to get the right dimensions, it worked on **IOS** but on **Android** it was calculating incorrect dimensions, this happened when the size of the image was too large, after reading a few articles and comments I analyzed that there might have been a problem in Fresco, I was unable to solve this problem.

```js
//returns wrong dimensions
Image.getSize(myUri, (width, height) => {setState({width, height})});
```

```js
 const setImageSize = (imageUrl:any) => {
        const img = new Image();
        img.src =`https:${imageUrl}`;
        img.onload = () => {
           console.log(
            "height-:", img.height,
            "width-:", img.width
            );
           
        };
   };

  useEffect(()=>{
     setImageSize(image)
  },[])
```

After that I tried to write a function that would call this url and would get dimensions, but I can not create constructor function with new Image() it's throws error TypeError: Object is not a constructor (evaluating 'new _reactNativeElements.Image()'). I do not know what to do or where to find the solution. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Image.getSize(myUri, (width, height) => { this.setState({ width, height }) });
```

[Refer to this!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31654244/react-native-retrieve-actual-image-sizes)